# Upgrade to 18.x bluetooth problems: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, bluez, bluetooth-speaker

Since I've upgraded tot Ubuntu 18.04 (and afterwards to 18.10) I'm having problems with Bluetooth connection. For instance, the music with my Bluetooth speaker lags seriously. Upon investigating `dmesg`I'm encountering lots of these errors:

```
Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
```

I tried to update `bluez`(5.48 -> 5.50) through the official PPA, but this did not work out.

Output from `lsusb | grep Blue`

```
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 0930:0508 Toshiba Corp. Integrated Bluetooth HCI
```

Strangely, I have 2 Bluetooth devices list when executing `rfkill list`

```
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Output from `dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'` might indicate some problems with the firmware:

```
[    0.069143] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[   18.813225] toshiba_bluetooth: Toshiba ACPI Bluetooth device driver
[   19.651213] iwl4965 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 228.61.2.24
[   55.834864] iwl4965 0000:01:00.0: Enabling power save might cause firmware crashes
[ 1204.278716] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[ 1204.278758] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[ 1204.278764] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[ 1204.278771] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[ 1204.278783] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[ 1204.664153] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 1204.664155] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[ 1204.664162] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 1204.769152] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[ 1204.769161] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[ 1204.769172] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

My kernel version:

```
4.18.0-10-generic
```

How could I solve this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has disappeared without any action from my side, probably an update or so.

I Will marked this as solved.

Wouter